# firestore security rules: check if user in array of banned users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a users collection that looks like:

`/users/{userId}` that has an array of maps that looks, for example, like

```
blockedUsers: [
  {user: "1", userName: "un1", displayName: "dn1"}, 
  {user: "4", userName: "un4", displayName: "dn4"}
]
```

I've denormalized the banned user data to simplify things.
I'm trying to setup firestore rules to prevent a banned user from replying to messages by the user that banned/blocked them.

here's my rule I've setup, which doesn't work but I've spent quite a while trying to figure this out and am now turning to StackOverflow for help.

```
match /users/{user} {
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow create: if request.resource.id == request.auth.uid;               
  allow update: if request.auth != null && !resource.data.blockedUsers.hasAny[request.auth.uid];
}
```

**Update**
Here's the client side code that a user would use to reply:

```js
const processNewMessage = async (evt, newMessage) => {
  myMessage.value = myMessage.value.trim();

  if (evt.srcElement.textContent === "send") {
    if (replying.value === true) {
      const message = {
        originalMessage: {
          text: props.selectedMessage.text,
          photoUrl: props.selectedMessage.photoUrl,
        },
        reply: {
          user: uid,
          userDisplayName: auth.currentUser.displayName,
          userName: userName.value,
          text: newMessage,
          createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
          photoUrl: photoUrl,
        },
      };

      await updateDoc(doc(db, `users/${props.selectedMessage.user}`), {
        replies: arrayUnion(message),
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any necessary info.

[image]

Comment: Rules on their own do nothing; they only become active when you execute code against them. Please edit your question to show the minimal code that fail against these rules, or a screenshot of the rules playground (if that's where you're experiencing the problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!resource.data.blockedUsers.hasAny[request.auth.uid]` cannot work since the `blockedUsers` array is an array of compounded objects (or maps).

The object/map `{ displayName: 'Kamal', uid: 'U4Tuy6676...', userName: 'Kamal' }` is not equal to the string `'U4Tuy6676...'`.

I would suggest you duplicate your data and have another array only containing the blocked uids. It will be easier than building the map in the security rules (I'm even not sure that you can do so: AFAIK you will not be able to get the `userName` value from the ID token).

Comment: Thanks. I included an array called blockedUserIds and only have the UIDs in there.  So my rule is now ```!(request.auth.uid in resource.data.blockedUserIds);``` It's too bad because now that data is duplicated twice in my collection. I was so close ```resource.data.blockedUsers.toSet()``` almost got me there but adding ```.values()``` was throwing errors when I tried to run simulations against it.